# My java code is not returning expected output

Tags: java

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        while(x < 1) {
            System.out.print("a");
            if(x < 1)
                System.out.print(" ");

            x = x + 2;
            if(x > 1) {
                System.out.println("noise");
                x = x - 1;
            }

            if(x == 1)
                System.out.println("annoys");

            if(x > 0)
                System.out.println("an");

            System.out.print("");
            System.out.print("oyster");
        }
    }
}
```

I was writing this code to get the output as follows:

```
a noise
annoys 
an oyster
```

But after running my code it is printing "an" and "oyster" in different lines, I am a beginner in java, please help me and tell me why I am not getting the proper output.

Comment: Do you ___know___ what "println" does?... Would you like to read up the documentation first before asking?

Comment: because you are using `println()` instead of `print()`

Comment: And *please* put some effort into formatting code before you post it. Indentation greatly aids readability.

Answer (score 1):

`println()` writes the string and then moves the cursor to the next line.
What you want is:

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=0;
        while(x<1){
            System.out.print("a");
            if(x<1){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            x=x+2;
            if(x>1){
                System.out.println("noise");
                x=x-1;
            }
            if(x==1){
                System.out.println("annoys");
            }
            if(x>0){
                System.out.print("an");
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print("oyster");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `System.out.println("an");`

use `System.out.print("an ");` and you can even remove `System.out.print(" ");`

`public void println()` -Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

refer this for [basic difference between print() and println()](http://java-intellectual.blogspot.in/2011/10/what-is-difference-between-print-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

print writes the string in the same line and println writes to the next line.

delete this one

```
 System.out.println("an");
```

and use this

```
System.out.print("an");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have an idea of what System.out.println() does....

```
 **System.out.println("My name");**
```

This prints My name first and then cursor moves to the next line.

So

```
 **System.out.print("an");
 System.out.print(" ");
 System.out.print("oyster");**
```

will give you the output desired.

Comment: `System.out.println("a noise\nannoys\nan oyster")` does :)

Comment: I accept what you've said but the question asked by the user is from the book "Head-First Java" where in the code has to be formulated from the given snippets only. So, I tried helping him using the same snippets previously.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `System.out.println();` always prints whatever is passed to it followed by a **new-line character in the end**. So whatever is printed next will be printed on the next line.
If you want the line to be printed in the same line, use `System.out.print();`

So you would need to do this:

```
while(x<1){
            System.out.print("a");
            if(x<1){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            x=x+2;
            if(x>1){
                System.out.println("noise");
                x=x-1;
            }
            if(x==1){
                System.out.println("annoys");
            }
            if(x>0){
                System.out.print("an");
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print("oyster");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using the empty spaces and options given:

```
    while (x < 4){ //x = 0 
        System.out.print("a");
        if(x < 1){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("n");
        if(x < 1){
            System.out.print("oise");//Allowed two lines in this block
            x = x - 1;
        }
        if(x==1){
            System.out.print("noys");
        }
        if(x>1){
            System.out.print(" oyster");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        x = x + 2;
    }
```

Note:  You are not allowed to add more than 2 lines in any if block besides the one with the comment.